# Finding total count error in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have a written a query to get the total count. But it returns a syntax error. The query is as follows:

```
((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM References 
  WHERE DocumentID = 15354 AND CustomerID = 896  AND ReferenceType = 1) 
  + 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM References 
 WHERE DocumentID = 15354 AND ReferenceType = 0)) AS TotalReference
```

What can I do to fix the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an argument for the count() function call, and you are missing and AND (or OR) before ReferenceType = 1

```
((SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM References 
    WHERE DocumentID = 15354 
    AND CustomerID = 896 
    AND ReferenceType = 1) + 
 (SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM References 
    WHERE DocumentID = 15354 
    AND ReferenceType = 0)) AS TotalReference
```

Also, have you considered returing the count in just one subquery?

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM References 
    WHERE DocumentID = 15354 
    AND ((ReferenceType = 1 AND CustomerID = 896)
        OR (ReferenceType = 0))) AS TotalReference
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [References]
  WHERE DocumentID = 15354 AND CustomerID = 896 AND ReferenceType = 1) +
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [References]
     WHERE DocumentID = 15354 AND ReferenceType = 0))
AS TotalReference
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not much experience with SQL Server but I think it is the missing AND also I think a * is needed on the counts (in Oracle this is needed). Also in Oracle we would need a SELECT at the beginning (and from DUAL but this is not needed in SQL Server):

```
select 
((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM References 
WHERE DocumentID = 15354 
AND CustomerID = 896 
and ReferenceType = 1) 
+ 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM References 
WHERE DocumentID = 15354 
AND ReferenceType = 0)
) AS TotalReference
```